# How to disconnect user in Parse.com, when he connect other device?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I need do user logout, when he will do login in other device, because I save the ParseInstallation and I send a Push, the Push is send for multiples installations that user was logged and I want send the current installation that User is Online.

Answer (score 0):

Mmmm I faced something similar before, you have to deactivate the *Automatic User creation* in your project, then do:

```
ParseUser.logOut();
```

And it will not log you in Again. If still logging you in then maybe you should look at your session and delete it.